# How to use Naudio in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, naudio

I'm trying to use some functions of NAudio in my Unity project but don't know how to install NAudio in Unity.

What I tried:

· use NugetforUnity, installed Naudio, Naudio.core

· download Naudio-Unity.dll, put it in assets/Plugin/

When I add a script on a gameobject in my scene, write some code like:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using NAudio.Wave;
using NAudio.Wave.SampleProviders;
using Naudio-Unity;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {

        for (int n = -1; n < WaveOut.DeviceCount; n++)
        {
            var caps = WaveOut.GetCapabilities(n);
            Debug.Log($"{n}: {caps.ProductName}");
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
    }
}
```

There are still compile errors, Unity cannot recongnize WaveOut. Any help on this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using `naudio` in a **game**?  Particularly when Unity already provides you with audio playback, mixer and effects!  nAudio appears to have been written back in 2007 with most activity in the 2012-2015 period.

Comment: @MickyD I want some sound of my game using headphone as output device, others using speaker. I did a brief search and found naudio can implement this - and I tested naudio on a c# program, it works. However in order to make my game output sounds to two devices I need naudio be avaliable in Unity. Also the latest release of Naudio was in this May, so I guess it's not very outdated?

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered the same problem. The intuition thought is to download the dll file from NuGet Gallery. When I first copy to Plugins folder the Unity report error because of the windowsform api. I decided to download individual dll file and it can work.

[NAudio dll in Unity Plugins folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTuwS.png)

Answer (score 0):

Integration Naudio in Unity:
Open your Unity project and create a new C# script.

1 Open your C# script In Visual Studio

2 In Visual Studio, go to "Tools" > "NuGet Package Manager" > "Manage NuGet Packages for Solution".

3 In the "Browse" tab, search for "**NAudio**" and install the package.
**(install  version 1.8.0 becouse new versions cant work in Unity)**

4 Once the package is installed, you can use the NAudio library in your script by adding the following using statement at the top of your script:

```
using NAudio.Wave;
```

Thats general link to  Github
https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/releases

5 U need download
**NAudio-1.8.0-Release.zip** https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/releases/download/NAudio_1.8_Release/NAudio-1.8.0-Release.zip

6 In your Unity project, create a new "Plugins" folder in the "Assets" directory if one does not already exist.

7 Copy the **NAudio.dll** file and other from  **NAudio-1.8.0-Release.zip** into the "Plugins" folder.

Now u can Use NAudio

This example of code(if you use this example code dont forget change your path to file and check Name of Script :)):

```
using UnityEngine;
using NAudio.Wave;

public class AudioPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    private IWavePlayer wavePlayer;
    private WaveStream waveStream;
    private string audioFilePath = "D:/Walker Hayes - AA (Official Video).mp3";
    void Start()
    {
        // Create WaveStream obj for stream
        waveStream = new Mp3FileReader(audioFilePath);

        // Create WaveOut obj for play stream
        wavePlayer = new WaveOut();
        wavePlayer.Init(waveStream);
        wavePlayer.Play();
    }

    void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        //stop play
        if (wavePlayer != null)
        {
            wavePlayer.Stop();
            wavePlayer.Dispose();
        }
        if (waveStream != null)
        {
            waveStream.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Pika Choux had a good answer, but they were wrong with one crucial detail: it's entirely possible to use the latest (2.2.1) version with unity.

If you install NAudio normally via Nuget examine your `~/.nuget/packages` directory, you'll find that almost all of the different DLLs have `netstandard2.0` support (see screenshot below)... EXCEPT for the primary NAudio DLL itself. But we can work around that easily.

Instead of installing via Nuget to Unit, you can simply copy over all the `NAudio.*.dll` files from `netstandard2.0` to your Unity `Plugins` directory. Since these low level DLLs don't have other dependencies, that's all you should need. If you find that you're missing anything, [it's one of the two source code files from the main `NAudio` package (which does not have netstandard support) but you can just copy and paste or adapt as needed](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/tree/master/NAudio).

et viola, modern NAudio in Unity.

[image]